# Reading .tga image and copying it

Tags: c, tga

I am trying to copy all data of one .tga file and create new file with exactly same data.
Basicly it should copy image. (but i need to use this way because of teacher...)

**Program:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <assert.h>

typedef unsigned char byte;

typedef struct {
    byte id_length;
    byte color_map_type;
    byte image_type;
    byte color_map[5];
    byte x_origin[2];
    byte y_origin[2];
    byte width[2];
    byte height[2];
    byte depth;
    byte descriptor;
} TGAHeader;

typedef struct {
    byte red;
    byte green;
    byte blue;
} RGBPixel;

typedef struct {
    TGAHeader header;
    RGBPixel* pixels;
    int width;
    int height;
} Image;

bool image_load(Image* image, const char* path){
    FILE *file = fopen(path, "rb");

    memset(image, 0, sizeof(Image));
    fread(&image->header, sizeof(image->header), 1, file);

    assert(image->header.depth == 24);
    assert(image->header.image_type == 2);

    memcpy(&image->width, image->header.width, sizeof(image->header.width));
    memcpy(&image->height, image->header.height, sizeof(image->header.height));

    image->pixels = (RGBPixel*) malloc(sizeof(RGBPixel) * image->width * image->height);
    fread(image->pixels, sizeof(RGBPixel) * image->width * image->height, 1, file);

    fclose(file);

    return true;
}

void image_free(Image* image) {
    free(image->pixels);
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    Image image;

    if(!image_load(&image, argv[1])){
        printf("Could not load image");
        return 1;
    }

    FILE* fp;
    fp = fopen(argv[2], "wb");
    fwrite(&image, 1, sizeof(image), fp);
    

    fclose(fp);
    image_free(&image);
    return 0;
}
```

this image works with slight damage done to the image
[image]

but this image after copying is just bunch of random pixels
[image]

Slight damage done to image is acceptable but I need the image good enough so I can still say "it is A"...

**Notes:**

I have converted images to png so I can show them here.

I am using C on Linux.

Comment: Did you try to debug it? For instance looking at the files before and after in a hex editor?

Comment: So you basically just want want to copy a file?

Comment: Images and image formats are usually much harder than it seems. I recommend you find one or more libraries which supports reading the source file format, and writing the destination file format.

Comment: Yes I have tried debbuging it.

I am trying to keep it easy when I said just copying it but I also need to edit it.

Comment: I think, yes...

Comment: maybe print the header values after reading to see if they make sense

Comment: I was comparing this two cases and they seem correct